# How can I copy each value of an array for a certain number of times (Iteration over rows / column)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

I want to iterate through each value of my existing array. Each value should be copied in both ways (column/row) for a certain number of times. I want to increase the resolution, so to speak.

Simple example to understand my description:

```
array = np.array([[1, 2],[1,2]]) # Factor 3
```

Result should be:

```
arraynew = np.array([[1,1,1,2,2,2],[1,1,1,2,2,2],[1,1,1,2,2,2]])
```

Besides this example, I have to work with a bigger array, so it's not doable by hand.

Comment: did you look at the `np.repeat` docs?

Comment: What's the repeat pattern for changing a (2,2) into a (3,6)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643142/repeat-values-of-an-array-on-both-the-axes answer uses a double repeat to get a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Kroenecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) if you would like to *up-scale* your array an integer number of times.

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, 2],[1,2]]) # Factor 3 
factor = 3

np.kron(array, np.ones((factor, factor)))

# array([[1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.]])
```

Note: You are free to vary the `(factor, factor)` tuple to increase dim `0` and `1` by different factors, e.g. set it `(3, 2)`.

See also the docs for [`np.kron`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html)

If you would like to upscale a non-integer number of times and are using images, you likely want to use scaling with interpolation e.g [scipy.misc.imresize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html).

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2]

factor = 3

def solv_the_problem(factor):
    x=[]
    y = []
    for i in a:
        for _ in range(0, factor):
            x.append(i)

    for _ in range(0, factor):
        y.append(x)

    return y

vector = solv_the_problem(factor)
print(vector)
```