# Repeat values of an array on both the axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have this array:

```python
array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Returns:

```
123
456
789
```

How should I go about getting it to return something like this?

```
111222333
111222333
111222333
444555666
444555666
444555666
777888999
777888999
777888999
```

Comment: @Denny I was using for loops to achieve this however it was overly complex and I assume inefficient, in the future, I will add my attempts to the posts.  However I hope that this question with the answers will help someone else as due to the edit made by double-beep it is both clear and informative.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'd have to use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy-repeat) twice here.

```
np.repeat(np.repeat(array, 3, axis=1), 3, axis=0)

# [[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
#  [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
#  [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
#  [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
#  [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
#  [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
#  [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]
#  [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]
#  [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]]
```

Answer (score 9):

For fun (because the nested `repeat` will be more efficient), you could use `einsum` on the input array and an array of `ones` that has extra dimensions to create a multidimensional array with the dimensions in an ideal order to `reshape` to the expected 2D shape:

```
np.einsum('ij,ikjl->ikjl', array, np.ones((3,3,3,3))).reshape(9,9)
```

The generic method being:

```
i,j = array.shape
k = 3 # extra rows
l = 3 # extra cols
np.einsum('ij,ikjl->ikjl', a, np.ones((i,k,j,l))).reshape(i*k,j*l)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]])
```

What is however nice with this method, is that it's quite easy to change the order to obtain other patterns or work with higher dimensions.

Example with other patterns:

```
>>> np.einsum('ij,iklj->iklj', a, np.ones((3,3,3,3))).reshape(9,9)
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]])

>>> np.einsum('ij,kjil->kjil', a, np.ones((3,3,3,3))).reshape(9,9)
array([[1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7],
       [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8],
       [3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7],
       [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8],
       [3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7],
       [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8],
       [3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9]])
```