# How to "grow" a matrix in python by a factor of 2x2?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

for example, if I have an array that looks like:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

and I want to define a function that can turn this into:

```
[[1 1 2 2]
[1 1 2 2]
[3 3 4 4]
[3 3 4 4]]
```

in other words, every entry in the matrix turns into a square of 4 entries of that value? I provided a 2x2 matrix for simplicity but I'm planning on using this function for 2^n sizes.

Comment: Can you share some code that you have?

Comment: Does https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html help?

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643142/repeat-values-of-an-array-on-both-the-axes) might be relevant